# How to find out what version of mod_perl is installed?

Tags: perl, apache2

In order to debug my perl code I need to find out what version of `mod_perl` is installed.

How do I find out the version of `mod_perl` I have installed?

Comment: The version will also appear in your apache error log if you have server tokens on.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try:

```
perl -Mmod_perl\ 999
```

If that doesn't work, try:

```
perl -Mmod_perl2\ 999
```

The first checks for mod_perl, version 999. Since that doesn't exist, it will output the actual version you have installed or an error saying it can't be found in the @INC. The second does the same thing, but for mod_perl2.

Example output for me:

> > perl -Mmod_perl2\ 999
>
> mod_perl2 version 999 required--this is only version 2.000005. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.

Comment: +1 thx this was what i heve benn looking for (the second one worked)

Answer (score 7):

In general:

```
perl -Mmod_perl -E 'say $mod_perl::VERSION'
```

Comment: guess this is for the module prior to version 2, but +1 for the answer

Comment: @Thariama,This would work for mod_perl2 too, with a slight change: `perl -Mmod_perl2 -E 'say $mod_perl2::VERSION'`.

Answer (score 1):

For me above solutions didn't work. This, however, worked fine:

```
rpm -q mod_perl
```